# Mount an EBS volume to an existing mount point on EC2 instance (Linux)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mount-point

I have 2 EBS volumes - 8GB and 20 GB - attached to my Ec2 instance. The 8 GB one is already mounted on my EC2 instance on /. I want to mount the 20 GB one to / as well so as to make the total volume on '/' as 28 GB. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you resize the volume, increase the size of the volume to 28GB and expand the partition and volume
Refer : https://medium.com/@m.yunan.helmy/increase-the-size-of-ebs-volume-in-your-ec2-instance-3859e4be6cb7

Comment: That's what I did finally. Just wanted to know if the question asked has a possible way for implementation.

Comment: yes you can do, using the two disks you can create a logical volume and mount as /
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-add-disk-to-lvm-volume-on-linux-to-increase-size-of-pool/